# Troubles with installing gnu smalltalk

Tags: gnu, smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

im trying to install gnu smalltalk on ubuntu, i downloaded smalltalk from ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/smalltalk and i extracted the folder on the desktop.   When i'm into the smalltalk folder and i write "./configure" and all seems to be alright, the console shows "Now please type 'make' to compile. Good luck.",  but when i type "make", next to a little bit of work of computer the terminal shows the next message:

```
(many lines)
     .
     .
     .
libtool: link: cannot find name of link library for `/home/reikoo/Escritorio/smalltalk-3.2/libc.la'
make[2]: *** [gst] Error 1
make[2]: se sale del directorio «/home/reikoo/Escritorio/smalltalk-3.2»
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: se sale del directorio «/home/reikoo/Escritorio/smalltalk-3.2»
make: *** [all] Error 2
reikoo@reikoo-desktop:~/Escritorio/smalltalk-3.2$
```

i don't know what is wrong

Comment: Did you know that here on Stack Exchange you can ask questions to "Ask Ubuntu" instead of "Stack Overflow"?
There is a big knowledge base for Ubuntu there.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried to delete the file `libc.la` and calling `make` again? (As suggested [here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-smalltalk/2011-04/msg00160.html))

Have you installed all the [dependencies](http://smalltalk.gnu.org/blog/zuluuuuuu/installing-gnu-smalltalk-ubuntu-10-10)?