# Can't run GNU Smalltalk gst; fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Tags: ubuntu, gnu, smalltalk

I just installed GNU Smalltalk `gst` on Ubuntu and when I enter `gst` into the terminal, I get this:

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you try to install it with ubuntu package manager, or downloading from the project page? Possibly related: [How do i run gnu-smalltalk in ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63316621/14813970), [gst-browser fails to start](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52766461/14813970) and [Troubles with installing gnu smalltalk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10194839/14813970)

Comment: I installed with the package manager

Comment: In the answer to the first link, its said the problem is a conflict, because git also has something named gst. So probably uninstalling git first would solve it, but that's probably unnacceptable. Anyway, if you suceed installing it, you will enconter another hurdle I found myself recently. The class browser won't start (see the second link). Perhaps the only viable way is downloading and install from the project page. But I still didn't try this route mylself.

Comment: Do you need gnu-smalltalk specifically, or any smalltalk would be OK? It's not found in the repository, but the Pharo folks made super easy to install this smalltalk flavor. You can do it with just one line in the terminal: "curl -L https://get.pharo.org/64/ | bash" (64 bit version). For more information, see https://pharo.org/download

Comment: Although this is a duplicate of the linked question, the answer in that link only answers the *why* but not the *how*. The *how* is noted in my answer to this question. So I would argue that it was not really answered.

Comment: @lurker I argee; thanks for the feedback. I have instead nominated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63316621/how-do-i-run-gnu-smalltalk-in-ubuntu as a duplicate of this question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i run gnu-smalltalk in ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63316621/how-do-i-run-gnu-smalltalk-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there's a conflict between the Smalltalk `gst` command and, evidently, an alias provided by the `git` package installation called `gst` which probably does a `git status`. This cause has been indicated in other linked answers (*e.g.*, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63316621/how-do-i-run-gnu-smalltalk-in-ubuntu)), but those answers don't tell you what to do to solve it.

There are a couple of ways this can be solved easily:

You can undo the alias that the `git` installation setup by doing an unalias in your login profile. Make sure you put it after any global profile is executed:

```
unalias gst
```

Or, if you want to keep the `gst` alias as `git status`, create a new alias for GNU Smalltalk, such as:

```
alias gnust={path to your GNU Smalltalk gst program}
```

Then just type `gnust` to get Smalltalk.